# jQuery draggable sometimes work sometimes not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

Hi I have a serious problem with jquery, sometimes draggable() work and sometimes not!! i don't know what to do or is my work wrong??!!!
I made a very very simple of code that doesn't work for me, can anyone tell me what's wrong?? I recently used dreamweaver CC and i thought that that is the problem but even codes that i written whit notepad++ doesnt work;

> all of the files are in root folder:

thanks

here is HTML -->

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
<html>
```

CSS -->

```
div{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery -->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').draggable();
});
```

Comment: When does it not work? What triggers this not to work?

Comment: It's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rWn9J/ when does it not work?

Comment: it follows a rule that I can't understand :D
it's really random :((
here is the link on my laptop:
[link](http://2.176.186.244/bidemajnun1)

Comment: you should probably put this script `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>` as the last one, not the first

Comment: @Stilly.stack wooow I didn't know that that was important!!
thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Stilly.stack that worked for this code but with my main program here doesn't work 
[link](http://2.176.186.244/bidemajnun)